# OpenCV with Nvidia VPI (Vision Programming Interface), core dumped

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm playing around with Vision Programming Interface (VPI) and trying to bend images. I came across this Lens Distortion Correction example (https://docs.nvidia.com/vpi/algo_ldc.html) and added some code so it takes an input image and shows the undistorted output image. The following code runs fine and I'm able to view the output image.

I'd like to run it in a loop for a video input. As soon as I uncomment the "videoCapture" line, I get the following error:

"Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Anyone able to help me use this code for video input?

```
import vpi
import numpy as np
import cv2
import PIL
from PIL import Image

img = cv2.imread('input.jpeg')

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


vpi_image = vpi.asimage(np.asarray(img))

grid = vpi.WarpGrid((2064,1544))

sensorWidth = 7.12
focallength = 3.5

f = focallength * (2064 / sensorWidth)

K = [[f, 0, 2064/2],
    [0, f, 1544/2]]

X = np.eye(3,4)

warp = vpi.WarpMap.fisheye_correction(grid, K=K, X=X,
                                    mapping=vpi.FisheyeMapping.EQUIDISTANT,
                                    coeffs=[-0.01, 0.22])

with vpi.Backend.CUDA:
    output = vpi_image.remap(warp, interp=vpi.Interp.CATMULL_ROM, border=vpi.Border.ZERO)

with output.rlock():
    output = Image.fromarray(output.cpu()).save('output.jpeg')

pil_image = PIL.Image.open('output.jpeg').convert('RGB')
cv2_image = np.array(pil_image)
cv2_image = cv2_image[:, :, ::-1].copy()

cv2_image = cv2.resize(cv2_image, (920,590))
img = cv2.resize(img, (920, 590))

sbs = cv2.hconcat([img, cv2_image])
cv2.imshow("sbs", sbs)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: The line cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
throws the error? Are you able to use VideoCapture(0) in a smaller example, or what does this problem have to do with vpi?

Comment: Having some trouble putting code in the comments but yes, I just tried with a smaller example: 

https://docs.nvidia.com/vpi/1.1/algo_persp_warp.html
 
Adding:

# cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
img = cv2.imread('input.jpeg')

I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped) as soon as I uncomment 'cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)'

Comment: Which I guess is a bit strange since the other cv2 method works fine (imread). Btw, I'm on a Jetson AGX running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: For clearification, I **am** able to run VideoCapture method in other scripts without importing VPI.

Comment: Can you provide a simple videocapture code that works until you uncomment the minimum number of vpi code lines (e.g. import vpi)? Just ask guess, but maybe vpi itself uses opencv and there is version conflict?

Comment: Stupid question but should it matter if I import cv2 or VPI first? I mean, at the top of my code? I think I have **something** working and as far as I can tell, the difference lies which library I import first.

Comment: Probably an opencv version mismatch. I dont know how python works, but if vpi imports its own open version your own opencv import might conflict?

Comment: Yeah, just tested. It works when I import cv2 first. Weird :) Next problem is to show the output. At the moment I'm getting "src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar" when trying to show the output using cv2.imshow.

Thanks for your help so far, Micka